# Network tab table data retrieval name , size

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to retrieve the name , initiator and size values for the requests as in attached image from the browser network tab.

For example the first request has name value of "index.html" , the second of "index.js" etc...
Is this possible by using java + selenium .

At the moment I'm able to retrieve request's method, headers, url etc.
Thanks in advance, have looked for answer quite some time , but found nothing which was of help to me.

[Image of what I want to retrieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDKpj.png)

I retrieved request headers , url , method and such with ease , but getting info from the main table is making me trouble.
I have this block of code so far:

```
    public void manipulateNetworkTab() {
        devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(),
                Optional.empty(),
                Optional.empty()));

        devTools.addListener(Network.requestWillBeSent(), request -> {
            System.out.println("--------------------Request data--------------------");
            System.out.println("Request headers: " + request.getRequest().getHeaders());
            System.out.println("Request url: " + request.getRequest().getUrl());
            System.out.println("Request method: " + request.getRequest().getMethod());
            System.out.println("Request initiator: " + request.getInitiator());
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
        });
```